# append color to ion-header when scrollTop is greater than 40 in ionic3

Tags: typescript, scroll, styles, ionic3

iam trying to add a color to ion-header when the scrollTop is greater than 40, 
 and again if i scrool to top is 0 then again my header wants to be transparent but it is not happening..

**what i tried is**

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AboutTripPage {
  constructor(){}

    scrollHandler(event){
    console.log("####SCROLL EVENT : ",event.scrollTop)
    if(event.scrollTop > 40){
      let css = ".toolbar-background {background-color: #D3300E !important;}";
      this.document.body.innerHTML.append = this.document.body.innerHTML + "<div><style>" + css + "</style></div>";
    }
  }
}
```

### my html

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar transparent  class="cus-header"> // here i made the header transparent
    <ion-title >My Trips</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content  (ionScroll)="scrollHandler($event)"> // here if when i scroll then i want to add a different color and i again scrollTop is 0 again my header want to transparent 

</ion-content>
```

Comment: what is not happening? the change in color? or making it transparent again?

Comment: both are not happening,it is not working, showing some error of `cannot append of string` @Suraj Rao